# iterate control names using a counter

Tags: c#, .net

I have over 100 buttons in a windows form an I want to access their name for command `Button.PerformClick()` based on the counter in a for loop. For example: `Button + Convert.Tostring(Counter).PerformClick()` How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method to loop through all of your buttons:

```
foreach(var button in this.Controls.OfType<Button>())
{
    // do something with button
    button.PerformClick();
}
```

For loop version:

```
for(int i=0; i<counter; i++)
{
   string name = "Button" + i;
   if(this.Controls.ContainsKey(name))
   {
      var currentButton = this.Controls[name] as Button;
   }
}
```

Note: This answer assumes that your buttons are direct child elements of your `Form`.If `Buttons` inside of a `Panel` then you should access `ControlCollection` of your panel with `panelName.Controls` instead of `this.Controls`.

Comment: this.Controls.OfType<Button>() gives an error: 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection' does not contain a definition for 'OfType' and no extension method 'OfType' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @ComputerUser what version of .NET Framework you are using? you should add a reference to System.Linq with: `using System.Linq;`

Comment: It must be .NET 2.0 because of client's restrictions.

Comment: @ComputerUser okey then use For loop version :) and make sure your button names are correct.I assume they are something like: `"Button1, Button2 etc..."`

Comment: One more question, can I get a count of total number of buttons that are present in a Windows Form in .NET 2.0 ? Or in other words, can I get type name of a control in .net 2.0 ?

Comment: @ComputerUser yes, loop through your all controls with `foreach(var control in this.Controls)` then use an if statement to check whether type of the current control is button or not like this: `if(control is Button)` use a variable for count and increment it for every button

Comment: @ComputerUser, you could also try a loop like this: `foreach (var c in this.Controls) if (c.GetType().Name.ToString() == "Button") ((Button)(c)).PerformClick();` (+1 btw Selman22)